# Javascript document.getElementById function not returning checkbox value to HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have been searching for an answer everywhere but just can not find what I need.

I have a webpage that has an HTML table on the left column and an HTML form on the right column. When I click on a row in the table on the left I want it to display the values in the form on the right.

I have this working perfectly for the text fields on the form, but not for the two checkboxes. My javascript will return either true or false or checked and unchecked to the `document.getElementById` within the script itself by using `alert();` but I have no idea what it needs to allow the checkboxes to display these values. I thought the `document.getElementById` would return the values but it seems it does not.

I have tried all kinds of conveluted ways to get this to work but can not seem to get the correct code needed.

I am new to all this so there is most likely something really simple I am missing.

This is the HTML form code:

```
<div class="column right">
  <table>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <div class="lockinv">
        <form autocomplete="off" name="lockform" class="keyassign" action="includes/lockinventory.inc.php"
          method="post">
          <label id="inventory" for="locknum">Lock Number</label>
          <input id="invlocknum" type="text" name="locknum" value="" required>
          <label id="inventory" for="locktype">Lock Type</label>
          <input id="invlocktype" type="text" name="locktype" value="" required>
          <label id="inventory" for="keycode">Key Code</label>
          <input id="invkeycode" type="text" name="keycode" value="" required>

          <label id="inventory" for="lockengraved">Lock Engraved</label>
          <input id="invlockengraved" type="hidden" name="lockengraved" value="0">
          <input id="invlockengraved" type="checkbox" name="lockengraved" value="1">

          <label id="inventory" for="lockmastered">Lock Mastered</label>
          <input id="invlockmastered" type="hidden" name="lockmastered" value="0">
          <input id="invlockmastered" type="checkbox" name="lockmastered" value="1">

          <label id="inventory" for="locknote">Lock Note</label>
          <textarea id="inventorynote" name="locknote" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea>

          <div class="wheel">
            <?php
              if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
                  if($_GET["error"] == "lockexists") {
                      echo "<p>Lock Already In Inventory!</p>";
                  }
                  else if ($_GET["error"] == "lockexistsfailed") {
                      echo "<p>Lock Already In Inventory!</p>";
                  }
              }
            ?>
          </div>

          <input id="bt6" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
          <button id="bt6" type="reset" name="button">Cancel</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript"></script>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#lockTable td').click(function () {

      var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
      var locknum = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
      var locktype = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
      var keycode = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text();
      var engraved = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").find(":checkbox");
      var mastered = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").find(":checkbox");
      var locknote = currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text();

      var lockengraved = engraved.prop("checked");
      if (lockengraved === true) {
        $grved = "checked";
      } else {
        $grved = "unchecked";
      }

      var lockmastered = mastered.prop("checked");
      if (lockmastered === true) {
        $msted = "checked";
      } else {
        $msted = "unchecked";
      }

      document.getElementById('invlocknum').value = locknum;
      document.getElementById('invlocktype').value = locktype;
      document.getElementById('invkeycode').value = keycode;
      document.getElementById("invlockengraved").value = $grved;
      document.getElementById('invlockmastered').value = $msted;
      document.getElementById('inventorynote').value = locknote;

      alert(document.getElementById("invlockengraved").value);
      alert(document.getElementById("invlockmastered").value);

    });
  });
</script>
```

```
<p id="invlocknum"></p>
<p id="invlocktype"></p>
<p id="invkeycode"></p>
<p id="invlockengraved"></p>
<p id="invlockmastered"></p>
<p id="invlocknote"></p>
    
<p id="info"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: You have an input type checkbox, input type hidden, and paragraph element which all share the exact same `id` value. An `id` must be unique to the entire document, and this is likely why you are not getting the results you expect when querying an element, since `document.getElementById(...)` will not know which element you are trying to reference.

Comment: I am trying to make the form dual purpose, if I click on the table row the form is in edit mode to allow edits to the existing lock, which I would like the checkboxes to show the what is checkboxes are checked in the table. If I enter a new lock info and check the appropriate checkboxs it saves that info to the database. So I needed the two inputs one to provide the "1" and the other so I didn't get a 'value not set' error or something to that nature. Is that possible or am I setting myself up for a big headache?

Comment: It sounds like you would like the values to be represented in a couple places, like the table and the form. That is fine, but they still should not have the same id value. In order to bind the value between the separate elements, you can listen for changes and update the others with an event listener. You can look more into "data binding with vanilla js" which may help you here.

Comment: Jacob K per your suggestion I removed the hidden Input and changed the Input Type to Text on the remaining Input and it will show the value I assigned in the javascript. So at least I know the script is working and is returning the value, however, it still will not check the checkbox. At least I know now that the script IS returning the value, I can now concentrate on the form to get it to work.
Thanks Jacob

Comment: *You have to use unique IDs.* The input type isn't the problem; the duplicate IDs are the problem.

Comment: I removed the duplicate IDs and it still does not show the checkbox status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue. I had to modify my if statement in the Javascript to the following. Works the way I want it to. Thanks to all that helped.

```
var lockengraved = engraved.prop("checked");
    if (lockengraved === true) {
      document.getElementById("invlockengraved").checked = lockengraved;
    }else if (lockengraved === false) {
      document.getElementById("invlockengraved").checked = lockengraved;
    }
```